# super keyword usage

Tags: solidity, remix

Have this contract from oz

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Votes.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Permit, ERC20Votes {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") ERC20Permit("MyToken") {}

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _afterTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function _mint(address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._burn(account, amount);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me why exactly we are using super._mint(to, amount)? I see no difference in code execution when I simply not putting it here. Also can't get why specify override(ERC20, ERC20Votes) instead of just override? I thought It will resolve in correct order anyway? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expanding on what @Kof said.

This doesn't accomplish anything.

```
    function _mint(address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._mint(to, amount);
    }
```

It calls the inherited contract (`super`) and `_mint()` without changing anything, so it's a replacement `internal` function that doesn't change anything.

If you check `mintable` on the wizard page, you'll see:

```
    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
```

That's a `public` function, so anyone can call it, but it also adds access control (`onlyOwner`). *Then*, it uses the provided `internal` `_mint()` function.

Guidance is not always as helpful as one might like. The main takeaway is the *internal* function has no access control and it's not exposed to the outside. It should only be used by a function you make that knows what it's doing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._burn(account, amount);
    } can be safely deleted? even thou we have internal virtual in the parent one?

Comment: You don't need that or `_afterTokenTransfer()`. Same logic. `virtual` means you _can_ override it, but you're not obliged to. Those internal functions are there to use _if you need to_. A common pattern is to call `_mint()` from the constructor so the supply isn't capped at 0. Similarly, if you want your users to be able to `burn()`, then make a `public` `burn()` function that relies on the internal `_burn()` function.

Answer (score 0):

OZ's methods starting with `_` are internal both for a clear distinction against external methods.

The `_mint` doesn't make role checks, etc. it just mints, so it must not be public/external.

You don't need to override these at all, whatever function which mints should just call `_mint(...)`.

You can mint in your constructor, or in a special method that requires a specific amount to be paid, etc.

Comment: that's the question, OZ says clearly that I need to overwrite it. You can check this in OZ wizard https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard